# make a website compatible with android

Tags: android, web

How can I make a website(which is exist before) compatible with android?
So that we can use every functionality of that website on our android device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this link: http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/targeting.html. The same rules would apply for making a website. One of the most important things is adding this line:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

This tells the browser to set the zoom level according to the device width. Otherwise the site will be zoomed out a lot and the user will have to zoom in to see the text properly.

- Almost all of your website's functionality will work in the Android browser unless you have some really screwed up Javascript code.
- Have a different [stylesheet](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/) for the mobile browser.
- Keep lower resolution graphics as bandwidth is a huge issue on phones. An EDGE network is too slow and even 3G speeds vary a lot.
- Do not keep the pages too long. Display sections as [Accordion](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/) menus which will expand/contract when the user clicks on the headers.
- Do not keep drop down menus which are activated on mouse hover. There is no hover state on the phone.

[This](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/03/how-to-build-a-mobile-website/) article from SmashingMagazine has a couple of other tips.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) here. I did this with an Internal site of mine. Basically I scaled it down in size and graphics. Depending on the amount of content it could be easy or more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

rewrite/modify it to be compatible with mobile browsers.  Its not something that you can just add a stylesheet for.

Comment: I have no idea. can you suggest me how to do it?

Comment: You have all the answers here, especially the link to webview, since that is where to begin. Time to dig in and learn.

Answer (score 0):

Android's webbrowser, at least for recent versions of Android, is quite powerful, and quite close, in terms of features, to a desktop one.

So, if your website doesn't do any too-fancy / special stuff *(like super-recent HTML5)*, it should work quite well on an Android device.

Note, though, that if you want your website to work on a mobile device, you'll have to at least think about :

- The fact that 3G *(or worse)* network is slow *(bandwith is not great ; and ping is not good either)* ; don't make your pages too heavy.
- The screen is small : don't put too much data on it
- Using touch-screens with big *(compared to the screen's size)* is hard and not precise : use big links, don't have links too close to each other.